# Unobtrusive Ajax returns "The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context" in ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-ajax

If I start a new project in ASP.NET 4.5, select Manage NuGet packages, search for Ajax, then install Unobtrusive Ajax, I can then go into my .cshtml file and type `@Ajax.___`, e.g. `@Ajax.beginForm`.

If I create a new project with ASP.NET Core, I cannot, where instead it gives me this error:

> The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context

I want to make a Form with an Ajax call as you could do in ASP.NET, such as:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EmployeeMaster", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp" })) {
    ...
    }
}
```

In the above, I can see that `Ajax` is an object of type `AjaxHelper` which comes from `System.Web.MVC.WebViewPage... so maybe it was never meant to be available for .NET Core?

Anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: is there Ajax library in json.package?

Comment: There is no json.package, but there is a bower.json and its an included dependency

Comment: im not sure about this but im only writing this because you havent really got any other responses. dot net core needs to have ajax library and ajax wont be accepted by default unlike that in MVC. try adding it in bower itself or just install the nuget package

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the `Ajax.BeginForm()` methods do not work in ASP.NET Core, the actual Unobtrusive Ajax HTML does. The C# methods just help generate the HTML form tags. Forgive me if this syntax is wrong; this is from memory, but you get the idea:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EmployeeMaster", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp" }))
{
    //form content
}
```

becomes

```
<form asp-action="EmployeeMaster" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="divEmp">
    <!-- form content-->
</form>
```

**NOTE:** The above HTML STILL needs the Unobtrusive Ajax JS files for it to wire up these `data-*` attributes correctly. This is not a part of ASP.NET Core MVC.

Answer (score -1):

What is the equlivalent of OnSuccess

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EmployeeMaster", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp", OnSuccess="ShowMessage" }))
{
    //form content
}
```

Comment: Nevermind this did the trick

<form asp-action="EmployeeMaster" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="divEmp" data-ajax-success="SuccessMessage" >